# ff object length is restricted to 32 bit integer in 64 bit Windows

Tags: r

I am using 64 bit R in 64 bit Windows. But when running following statement

```
fi <- ff(vmode="integer", length=2147483648)
```

R produced an error message saying

`length must be between 1 and .Machine$integer.max`

This doesn't make good sense for 64 bit R. Is there any way to avoid this restriction?

Comment: Look at .Machine$integer.max in your (unspecified) 64 bit version of R. (It's going to be what it always has been). R 3.0+ does allow longer 53 bit indices (the length of the numeric mantissa), so it is possible that the authors of ff have not yet changed their tests in the code.

Comment: http://google-opensource.blogspot.ca/2011/11/bringing-64-bit-data-to-r.html

Comment: What version of R are you using? >= R 3.0.0?

Comment: Please read my comment again. I was agreeing with your statement (if you are on 3.0.+ which is not yet clear) but I was saying the authors of ff may not have made changes that take advantage of that.

Comment: @DWin Oh. I saw earlier version of the comment. Thanks for clarification and your info.

Comment: @SimonO101 Yes, exactly 3.0.1

Comment: In that case, I will try to remove that restriction in ff script and see if it's working.

Comment: There's no way around this, R 3.0.0 introduced 64-bit indices but it's done using doubles. The ff author told me he is not able to put in the time to work around this to provide ff vectors longer than the 32-bit integer limit. (You can easily make lists of arrays at the limit and put your own wrappers around that, it works well. But, it's disappointing).

Comment: @mdsumner Thanks a lot for contacting the author about this and suggesting alternatives. Yeah, looking at the c/c++ code, I realized that it's not only changing type of argument. Maybe restructuring c/c++ code with RCpp would help though. I am with you that it's disappointing as ff is otherwise an amazing package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem by changing/recompiling source of the package.

Among lots of features from ff, I only needed to create ff object and to call get/set subscript methods so my scope was narrow enough for me to do this in a night but all credit goes to the original author who organized the source very well. In fact, the author well prepared for this issue and made C macros for different type of index and size. I just used the C macros to do what I want.

Here is roughly what I did.

1. Remove all error checking integer for size (length) of ff object in ff function
2. Use as.double instead of as.integer when passing the size and pagesize to C function `new`.
3. In ff.h, I redefined following macro and its corresponding part in ff.cpp

   ```
   #define FF_DECL_TYPE(NAME,TYPE) \
     FF_DECL_TYPE2(NAME,TYPE,int,int) \
     FF_DECL_TYPE2(NAME##_d,TYPE,double,double)
   ```
4. in r_ff_new method of r_ff.c, replace all *_new functions with *_d_new and use asReal instead of asInteger for len and pagesize

I am sure there are more things to do but in my initial test, I could execute the statement in my question above and could get/set any element of the array in R. My object is to preprocess and analyze, for example, 30 GB data cube without leaving R. And I am this close.

Comment: Nice! Would be great if it was included in the ff package!

Comment: @jwijffels Although my change is not even near complete, I am willing to contribute if there is any chance. Once I finish (test/debug) this change, I will try to contact the author.